# Mutations of an $A_n$ quiver to reach $A_n$ straight orientation

Tags: quiver, cluster-algebra

(1)For a quiver $A_n$ of arbitrary orientation does there exist a finite sequence of quiver mutations that can mutate it to $A_n$ straight orientation $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow n$ or its opposite quiver $1\leftarrow 2\leftarrow\cdots\leftarrow n$?

(2)If the answer to (1) is true, can we make sure all mutations in the procedure are at sources and sinks only? (So that during the process we always have a quiver $A_n$?)

Comment: You copied these questions out of a problem list somewhere? What have you tried? Can you do this for small $n$?

Comment: Please, *please*, **please** read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I did not...This is a little combinatorial subquestion for my research on maximal green sequences..

I believe the answer to both (1) and (2) is yes. Also I believe this problem may be tackled by mutations at the middle vertices first.

Comment: (This is answered in pretty much every textbook treating represntations of quivers, by the way)

Comment: OK so I will continue to think about the problem myself..:-)

Comment: That is certainly the best thing you can do.

Comment: I know that this problem is equivalent to flipping zigzag graphs at maximums and minimums. This is how I think about it now..

Comment: I will write the answer myself later. I agree this is yes.
Ideas:
1.There is a bijection between an $A_n$ quiver and a zigzag graph of length $n-1$.
2.What matters is to flip an "arm" of the zigzag to the other direction. Do induction on it.
3.Flip all the arms so that we finally get a straight line segment.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez By the way, what books are you talking about? I only use the Introduction to representation theory book by Etingoff et al and notes by Professor William Crawley-Boevey and talk notes by Professor Claus Ringel. I seriously have never seen that before...

Comment: This is done in the book by Assem+Skowroński+Simson, the one by Pierce on associative algebras or, if I recall correctly, the one by Auslander+Reiten+Smalø.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks...I just got this book by Assem-Simson-Skowronski earlier this week. I have read parts of Auslander-Reiten-Smalo which is hard but I have never reached this part..